# Dropdown menu not appearing below a specific button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently making a dropdown menu (for my school's activity). Though for some reason, the menu works but it only appears below the first button.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1peaco24/

HTML:

```html
        <DIV class = "bar">
        <DIV class = "dropdown">
            <button class = "drop" onclick = "gpuFunction()">GPU Manufacturers</button>
            <button class = "drop1" onclick = "cpuFunction()">CPU Manufacturers</button>
            <button class = "drop2" onclick = "ramFunction()">RAM Manufacturers</button>
        <DIV class = "stuff" id = "dropDown">
            <a href="#">Nvidia</a>
            <a href="#">AMD</a>
            <a href="#">Asus</a>
            <a href="#">EVGA</a>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class = "stuff" id = "dropDown1">
            <a href="#">Intel</a>
            <a href="#">AMD</a>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class = "stuff" id = "dropDown2">
            <a href="#">HyperX</a>
            <a href="#">Corsair</a>
            <a href="#">Kingston</a>
            <a href="#">G. Skill</a>
        </DIV>
        </DIV>
        </DIV>
```

(this is my first post, pardon me if I have made any mistakes in creating it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is position the dropDown Elements relative to the buttons.

One way in which you can do that is, calculate the position of the button and the height of it. And then position the dropdowns.

```
// Here we select all the elements
const drop = document.querySelector(".drop");
const drop1 = document.querySelector('.drop1')
const drop2 = document.querySelector('.drop2')

const dropDown = document.getElementById("dropDown");
const dropDown1 = document.getElementById("dropDown1")
const dropDown2 = document.getElementById("dropDown2")

//Here we add a click event to the button
drop.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
//Here we get the Left and Top position of the button
const x = evt.target.offsetLeft
const y = evt.target.offsetTop
//Here we get the height of the button
const height = evt.target.offsetHeight

dropDown.classList.toggle("show")
//And here we position the dropdown relative to the button
dropDown.style.top = `${y + height}px`
dropDown.style.left = `${x}px`
})

drop1.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
const x = evt.target.offsetLeft
const y = evt.target.offsetTop
const height = evt.target.offsetHeight

dropDown1.classList.toggle("show")
dropDown1.style.top = `${y + height}px`
dropDown1.style.left = `${x}px`
})

drop2.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
const x = evt.target.offsetLeft
const y = evt.target.offsetTop
const height = evt.target.offsetHeight

dropDown2.classList.toggle("show")
dropDown2.style.top = `${y + height}px`
dropDown2.style.left = `${x}px`
})
```